# Display a tag only if there is a description

Tags: taxonomy, tags, description

I'm building a site glossary and trying to display only tags with descriptions. Is there a  way to determine if the description is available and only display the tag when it is?

Here is where I am so far.

```
    $tags = get_tags();
    if (tag_description($tag->term_id)) {
        if ($tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                echo '<dt><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></dt><dd>' . tag_description($tag->term_id) . '</dd>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object returned by `get_tags()` should have a `description` property, so you don't need to try to get it again. Just check to be sure `$tags->description` isn't empty. You should probably also reorganize so that you don't do anything at all unless `if($tags)`. Thus:

```
// Get ALL the tags!
$tags = get_tags( array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
if ($tags) {
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if ($tag->description) {
      echo '<dt><a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></dt><dd>' . $tag->description . '</dd>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's odd I'm finding that it's not updating the list when I add more. Does it only show tag that are attached to posts? If so, how would I display all tags?

Comment: Ah yeah, `get_tags()` excludes empty ones by default. I've updated my answer to get all of them. Untested, though :)

Comment: Looks like it's still only getting tags that are connected to posts. Also, how would you sort them by name instead of number of contained posts?

Comment: `get_tags()` is supposed to return tags alphabetically: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags . Do you have a plugin or code that could be interfering? The above really should work.

Comment: You're right, I apologize. It was "Role Scoper" I'm working to figure out what could cause that. Thanks for the help.